Why can a constant property in a struct be mutated in the initializer?
I'm interested to know the reasoning behind Swift Compiler's design to allow a property to be assigned a value at the initializer even if is defined as a constant. Shouldn't anything defined with let not be allowed to mutate at all?
Example code:
struct Exercise {
    let name: String
    
    // works fine (why?)
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    // throws error (makes sense)
    mutating func changeName(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}


Okay, so you declared name to be a constant. What is its value then? You still need to give it a value! And one of the places to do that is in init.

You are not mutating the constant in the initializer. You are initializing the constant with its initial (and only) value in the initializer.
This is all covered in the Initialization chapter of the Swift book. See the section Assigning Constant Properties During Initialization.
Also note that your explicit init is just replicating the default init you would have received for the struct if you had not provided any init at all.
struct Exercise {
    let name: String
    
    // throws error (makes sense)
    mutating func changeName(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let someExercise = Exercise(name: "Some Name")

The above code is identical to the code in your question. If you comment out the bad line in changeName, then the code works just fine.

If you change let name: String to something like let name: String = "Bob", then you can't set name in an initializer since name has already been initialized. Trying to set it in an initializer would then be an attempt to modify the constant. In fact, in such a case, there is no longer an implicit init(name: String) provided since name already has a value. Trying to add it explicitly (with self.name = name) results in the error:

Immutable value 'self.name' may only be initialized once

